# Avoid Writing into intemediate Aggregate Store in Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

In my case I am executing `hopping window` e.g. `(100sec,1sec)`.

```
KTable<Windowed<String>, aggrTest> WinMinMax = Records.groupByKey().aggregate(new aggrTestInitilizer(), 
        new minMaxCalculator()
        , TimeWindows.of(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(100)).advanceBy(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1)),aggrMessageSerde);
```

But here number of messages in 100sec window are very large, this causes window execution to take large time. So, to improve this window execution time,

1. I want to avoid writing data into intermediate aggregate state store(which kafka streams write by default).
2. Also If (1) is not possible then can we store intermediate aggregate state generated by window in RAM instead of disk?(what are settings for same?)
3. Any further suggestions to improve window execution time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you implemented your `MinMaxCalculator()` but I assume it just compares the current min/max with the new value. Thus, the store only contains the current aggregation. -- Hence, the window size does not matter at all, as independent of the window size, you store just the key and the current aggregation result.

To address you questions:

1. By design, an aggregation needs a store to keep the current aggregation result -- thus, you cannot get rid of a store.
2. Yes, you can use in-memory store. The `aggregate()` method has an overload that allows you to put a custom store and there are utility classes to create in-memory stores. Check out the docs (btw: those API got simplified a lot in Kafka 1.0, so I would recommend to upgrade if you don't use 1.0 already): https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html#enable-or-disable-fault-tolerance-of-state-stores-store-changelogs
3. as explained above, the size of the window does not influence your computation "speed"

> Side notes:
>
> - if you go with in-memory state instead of RocksDB, you limit the store size to your RAM size -- this might become a problem if your retention time is large as state can become quite big
> - if you do rolling bounces, this will take more time as the state needs to be recreated by reading the full changelog topic -- RocksDB stores can recover from local disk what is much faster
> - you could try to stay with RocksDB and increase KTable cache size to improve performance: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/memory-mgmt.html

Comment: Addendum: Even if you go with an in-memory state store, your state store will still be fault-tolerant (unless you explicitly disable this).  That is, an in-memory store has the limitation, by design, that its data must fit into the available main memory of your application, but it is still fault-tolerant to prevent e.g. data loss if a machine crashes.

Comment: @MichaelG.Noll I have disabled logging for in-memory state-store associated with window aggregation, but still it writes aggregations on changelog in disk, why is this happening?